# Loading data from a slow source best practices

Tags: sql, ssis, etl, pervasive

I'm looking for any best practices when loading data from a source that in it's self is slow - either from high load on the server, low bandwidth or something else - and where you can't do anything about the performance on the source, only on the loading.

I have a data source, Pervasive PSQL Server 11.2, and a table with 30M+ records. I want to extract only the last two years of data. Anything using a WHERE statement makes the query run for 60+ minutes without sending any data. Doing a

```
SELECT * FROM [table];
```

works, but gets me 10+ years of data I don't need and takes so long I'm not able to run it every night. Setting AutoAdjustBufferSize to true improves performance but not nearly enough.

The date column is a DATE datatype column. I've tried YEAR(column) > 2018 and tried BETWEEN and converting the first four characters to INT but nothing have sped up the load time.

Comment: I'd try `column >= '2018-01-01'`, i.e. the columns itself, not as argument to a function.

Comment: I agree with the other comment.  Try setting a full date for the WHERE clause.  Also, check for an index on that field.  If one doesn't exist, add one.  It won't affect any existing apps and unless the application updates that table's structure in an update, you shouldn't have to add the index again.

Comment: I've tried '2018-01-01'. Unfortunately it still timed out after about an hour. There doesn't seem to be an index on the field and I can't add one. If I could change the source I would try a completely different approach I think.

Comment: Is this a one time load or will this be a daily process to pull the last two years of data?  Also, could you test exporting the data to a flat file locally on the server (the whole table), to isolate the problem.  Does that take an hour to export?

Comment: It will be a daily process. I'll try to get a local export in place. 
Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: @MagnusLander is the data something that is updated daily from previous years? if the data is old and untouched there's nothing wrong with staging the data to a "faster" place if you can implement tools to pull from multiple sources. We use PSQL its awful, and I moved maintain a second database pulling over "hot" data in order to get faster responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up doing a two stage solution. We load previous years into history tables (one time load or yearly maybe), then load current year weekly and load previous month + current month in a daily load. Limiting data that much made it possible to use WHERE statements. And I think it was a good enough data load pattern to use.